# TypeError: ‘DoesNotExist’ object is not callable

Tags: python, django

It's not always this code chunk but this is the most recent. It seems to be random, any thoughts?

```
try:
    u = User.objects.get(email__iexact=useremail)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    ...
```

Throws this error, randomly.

```
File "/srv/myapp/registration/models.py", line 23, in get_or_create_user
  u = User.objects.get(email__iexact=useremail)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
  return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 349, in get
  % self.model._meta.object_name)

TypeError: ‘DoesNotExist’ object is not callable
```

Comment: Sounds like you're performing a bad assignment somewhere.

Comment: Indeed. There's nothing "wrong" about the snippet you posted. Something somewhere else is causing the problem.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to trace this down? Like I said it's not just this code it seems to happen on the same modal though.  We can't replicate it so it's been impossible to debug.

Comment: Can you post full code? I think after your try/catch block you use this u variable with DoesNotExist object value. Maybe you'll need to set in except value to None.

Comment: It's not jus this chunk of code, it's happened in different parts of the app at random times.  The other confusing part as this code has worked fine for months and just all of a sudden are we getting these errors.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As Chris says in the comments above, your snippet is valid. Somewhere else in your code, you may be catching exceptions incorrectly.

You may have something like:

```
try:
    do_something()
except User.MultipleObjectsReturned, User.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

instead of:

```
try:
    do_something()
except (User.MultipleObjectsReturned, User.DoesNotExist):
    pass
```

Without the parentheses, the except statement is equivalent to the following in Python 2.6+

```
except User.MultipleObjectsReturned as User.DoesNotExist:
```

The instance of the `User.MultipleObjectsReturned` exception overwrites `User.DoesNotExist`.

When the same process handles a different request later on, you get 
the `TypeError` because your code is trying to call the exception instance which has replaced `User.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: That seems like a likely candidate

Comment: AWESOME!  Thanks, a quick grep for all the DoesNotExists showed the culprit.  except LoginKey.DoesNotExist, User.DoesNotExist:

Comment: Yep, this totally fixed an issue that's been bugging me for months. I just did a find in my project for "DoesNotExist," to see where I might be forgetting parens. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you sooooo very very very much!  I would never have thought of that.

Comment: Thanks! Made my night. I've been staring at this strange test failure for hours.