# Django model.DoesNotExist exception somehow replaced with an AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm experiencing an odd exception on a Django 1.5 site:

```
 "TypeError: 'exceptions.AttributeError' object is not callable"
```

Essentially it looks like the model.DoesNotExist exception has been replaced with an AttributeError.

The error is intermittent, but once it happens it seems to 'stick' until I restart the process, which makes me think it might be a case of the model class getting incorrectly set in the course of a particular request, and then persisting.

Bottom of traceback:

```
File "/opt/mysite/django/apps/profiles/models.py", line 353, in profile_from_cache
    profile = self.get(user=user_id)

  File "/opt/mysite/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/mysite/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 404, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)

TypeError: 'exceptions.AttributeError' object is not callable
```

Line of code from `django/db/models/query.py`:

```
if not num:
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
        "%s matching query does not exist." %
        self.model._meta.object_name)
```

So it looks as if it's trying to pass a message to the DoesNotExist exception on the model, but it's somehow been replaced by an AttributeError instead.

The issue only seems to happen from http requests - if I do the same action from the command line I just get a DoesNotExist exception (which is what should be happening).

I can't find any obvious reason this should be happening.  Any ideas?

(PS this seems to be the same issue.  The user's answer to it, I think, is wrong: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/k9JMyXlUt3Q)

### Possibly relevant code

Here is an outline of the model manager:

```
class CacheManager(models.Manager):
    def profile_from_cache(self, user_id=None):
        profile = cache.get("profile_%s" % user_id)
        if profile is None:
            try:
                profile = self.get(user=user_id)
            except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                return None
            cache.set("profile_%s" % user_id, profile, settings.CACHE_TIMEOUT)
        return profile

    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    caches = CacheManager()
```

Here's the line of code that seems to be causing the error.  In this case it's in some middleware, but there are a few different places, all causing the same thing.

```
Profile.caches.profile_from_cache(user_id=request.user.pk)
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual query ?

Comment: Have added some more details to my question.

Comment: I think this might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877717/1005499.  I'll report back if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because of incorrect syntax elsewhere in the project, that caught multiple exceptions like this:

```
try:
   do_something()
except AttributeError, Profile.DoesNotExist:
   pass
```

When it should have been this:

```
try:
   do_something()
except (AttributeError, Profile.DoesNotExist):
   pass
```

What was happening was that when this happened, `AttributeError` got assigned to `Profile.DoesNotExist` in memory, so when it was raised later, it was the wrong exception.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877717/1005499) for helping.