# Django user is still AnonymousUser after calling auth.login()

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication

I'm trying to log in a user after they scan an RFID tag on their ID badge, however after calling `auth.login()`, the user is not logged in, and `request.user` is still `AnonymousUser`.

I'm using the following view to authenticate the user:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                Models.People.objects.get(id_badge=form.cleaned_data['badge_number'], deleted=False, system_user=True)
            except Models.People.DoesNotExist:
                form.add_error('badge_number', 'Badge number not recognised')
                return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
            user = user.authenticate(id_badge=form.cleaned_data['badge_number'])
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse('main-menu'))
            else:
                form.add_error('badge_number', 'Badge number not recognised')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

I also have a custom authentication backend to check the badge numbers:

```
class RFIDBackend(object):
    def authenticate(id_badge=None):
        try:
            person = Models.People.objects.get(info1=id_badge, deleted=False, system_user=True)
        except Models.People.DoesNotExist, Models.People.MultipleValuesReturned:
            return None
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=person.login)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        if user.is_active:
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(id_badge=None):
        try:
            person = Models.People.objects.get(info1=id_badge, deleted=False, system_user=True)
        except Models.People.DoesNotExist, Models.People.MultipleValuesReturned:
            return None
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=person.login)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user
```

When trying to log in, the user is successfully redirected to the menu page, but then the template raises an error when it tries to put their name on the page:

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but to [avoid this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877340/typeerror-doesnotexist-object-is-not-callable/7877717#7877717), put your exceptions in a tuple: `except (Models.People.DoesNotExist, Models.People.MultipleValuesReturned):`.

Comment: The argument to `get_user` should be the user model's primary key. Is `id_badge` the primary key for your user model? Please show your User model.

Comment: @Alasdair I always forget about that one, thanks. The user model is Django's built in one (django.contrib.auth.models.User)

Comment: Since you are using the built in User, I think your `get_user` method is a problem, see my answer below. Second aside: you can return `redirect('main-menu')`, the `reverse` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_user` method should take the primary key of the user, not the `id_badge`. Since you are using the built in user, you could use the same implementation as Django's `ModelBackend`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class RFIDBackend(object):
    ...
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

You try extending this to do the checks on the `deleted` and `system_user` fields. If you do this, test to make sure it works as expected when a user is deleted, I'm not 100% sure it will lead to the user being logged out.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `cleaned_data` not `cleaned_date`?

```
Models.People.objects.get(id_badge=form.cleaned_data['badge_number'], deleted=False, system_user=True)
```

Comment: Yup, that's a typo on my end